# Wordpress - Show parent category AND subcategory name in subcategory archive URL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having some trouble with Wordpress `category/subcategory` archive URLs.

For example, I want to be able to display this archive:
 `http://faroutmagazine.co.uk/wp/track-of-the-day` while keeping its parent category in the URL, making it `http://faroutmagazine.co.uk/wp/music/track-of-the-day`

Previously, I was just getting a "This is embarrassing..." 404 message when accessing the `/music/track-of-the-day` URL (even though that's the one that was appearing in the View option under categories in the admin section of WP).

Now the View link in the admin area only shows me the `/track-of-the-day` URL, and this DOES display the category posts which is great, but I want it to include the parent category in the URL.

Is there anything I can do to  the `functions.php` file or any plugins I can add to make this happen? Please bear in mind that there are multiple subcategory archives on this site, and they should all contain the parent category in the URL.

***UPDATE:
I actually have just set everything up a different way now using Pages and showing category archives on pages as it's taking up too much time. Thanks for your answer though. People telling me to use `%category%/%postname%` as the permalink structure are incorrect - yes, this works for the POST urls but not for the archive category of the subcategory which is the problem I was actually looking for help with. If anyone can provide an answer, it would be appreciated, but I am using this workaround now as this was taking up way too much time trying to figure out.

Comment: http://woocommerce-url-builder.co.za/ is a paid plugin that sorts out this issue as well as removes /product-category/ and /product/ from product category's and products respectively.

Answer (score 19):

This happens because you chose category and subcategory from the right options tick boxes when editing the entry. Choose only the subcategory box in every entry and it will show the nested URL.

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't know and checked both the parent and child category. By selecting the child category it is now working as expected:

/category1/category2/post/

Even the bread crumb trail is working properly.

Comment: The answer is very general - You need to give instruction to make this answer useful for other users

Comment: This worked for me as well to fix the URL, but I need the pages to also be in their parent categories for sorting purposes =/

Comment: I am using a custom post type and needed to set a custom taxonomy for categories (since I don't want post categories mixed in with the custom post type), and I can't seem to get this working at all.  the slug for my custom taxonomy is `product_categories`, the custom post type is `product`, the rewrite slugs do not help, Permalink structure does not help either.  I simply want my urls to be:  `/category/subcategory/postname` but subcategories are not maintaining their parent categories in the url, so is like this:  `/subcategory/postname`, and `category/postname`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Not clear in WP, though.

Comment: omg you're right.... that works...!
directly to the article using domain.com/category/sub-category/article-title .... but when we call the domain.com/category/sub-category only 
it didnt show all the posts.... another unwanted behaviours from WP. :(

Answer (score 5):

To make this happen you need to make some change in permalinks

go to **Settings->Permalinks** then select custom structure and use this syntax " **/%category%/%postname%/** "in the field

Now save the settings and you can see the post url's using its category name in the permalink

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I did this already, and it worked fine for the post name, but not the subcategory archive. I actually have just set everything up a different way now using Pages and showing category archives on pages as it's taking up too much time. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 4):

You should set hierarchical value to true when you are defining your taxonomy.

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'mySlug', 'hierarchical' => true),`

Then if you have a subcategory the url will be shown like this:
http://example.com/taxonomy/parentCategory/subCategory/

I found this sloution here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155319/how-to-include-parent-terms-in-hierarchical-taxonomy-urls

Answer (score 3):

Actually hierarchical subcategory archive permalinks are default in wordpress.

If you have a "pretty permalinks" structure selected in settings > permalinks, like `/%postname%` for example, then category and subcategory archive urls should default to something like: 
`yourdomain.com/category-base/category/sub-category/sub-sub-category`

I had encountered a similar issue with a recent WP project, BUT I was using a plugin called [WP No Base Permalink](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-base-permalink/) in order to get rid of my category and tag base slugs in my archive permalinks. When I deactivated the plugin, category hierarchy suddenly returned to my archive permalinks (luckily this project was still in development, otherwise, I would have had some major 404 problems).

I have not yet found/tested another plugin for eliminating category/tag base slugs that will also preserve hierarchy in sub/category archive urls, but it turns out that I do not need that functionality for my current project.

Instead I am using the base slugs `blog-articles` and `blog-tags` for the standard categories and tags in order to set the blog taxonomies apart from other taxonomies.  Then I am using the plugin [Types](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) to create a custom post type and custom taxonomies for that post type. The Types plugin has an option in the advanced settings to set hierarchical taxonomy urls to `true` or `false` when creating a custom taxonomy.

Finally, I found a plugin called [Remove Taxonomy Base Slug](http://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-taxonomy-base-slug/) that effectively eliminates the default taxonomy term from the base slug of the taxonomy archive urls. And this, thankfully, does not interfere with the hierarchical sub/category urls, OR the base slugs for standard tags and categories.

So now, my blog categories/tags look like this:

`yourdomain.com/blog-articles/category/sub-category/` 
or `yourdomain.com/blog-tags/tag/`

And my custom post type categories/tags look like this:

`yourdomain.com/category/sub-category/` or `yourdomain.com/tag/`

Phew!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Setting Settings->Permalinks->Category base to '%category%' should give you what you want. According to WP doc:

> Nested sub-categories appear as nested directories in the URI

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks.

Comment: That didn't work. The individual posts work fine with both the category and sub-category in the URL (ie: http://faroutmagazine.co.uk/wp/music/track-of-the-day/temples-keep-in-the-dark/) but the sub-category archive still doesn't display: http://faroutmagazine.co.uk/wp/music/track-of-the-day/

Comment: This won't work. You just get the same category in the URL twice.

Answer (score 1):

The Permalinks settings should be like /%category%/%postname%/ ..

Comment: This didn't work - I already tried that and mentioned it in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

If use custom permalinks settings as %postname% only, it will make your url in the form of .../category/subcategory.

Comment: This didn't work - it was fine for the full post URL, but not for the subcategory archives - they had a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress plugin to remove 'category' from url 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/
 and then follow the instruction given by Maruti

Comment: I tried this already - the post links have the category and subcategory in the URL - that's not the problem. The problem is that it won't show a subcategory archive while keeping the parent category in the URL.