# Wordpress Job Manager - Show URL structure as /[listing-category]/[listing-child-category]

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I am trying to change the standard permalink structure of the job listing feature from Wordpress' Job Manager.

The aim is to stop it having "listing-category" in the URL and changing it to the actual parent category name.

The current URL structure outputs:

```
/listing-category/marketing-executives
```

I would like this to be:

```
/marketing-roles/marketing-executives
```

for example. "marketing executives" is the child category of "marketing roles" (the parent category).

I have tried threads such as [Wordpress - Show parent category AND subcategory name in subcategory archive URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538265/wordpress-show-parent-category-and-subcategory-name-in-subcategory-archive-url) and scoured through Wordpress' developers pages such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/ with no success.

I have also taken a punt on making the custom permalink structure with strings such as:

```
/%listing-category%/%listing-child%/
```

again with no success. (It was a very big punt!)

Can anyone guide me as to where I will find the documentation to achieve this, or have any suggestions on what changes I need to make? No doubt it will require custom PHP development which I can happily make with some guidance.

Thanks in advance