# Wordpress php Dropdown Click and Go

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code that lists all my product categories in a dropdown menu, but when I select a category from the dropdown menu, nothing happens:

```
<?php
$args = array('hide_empty'=> 0,
    'taxonomy'=> 'product_cat','show_option_all'=> '- Search by category...',
    'hierarchical'=>1,'orderby'=> 'name',
    'echo'=>0);

$cats = wp_dropdown_categories($args);
echo $cats;
?>
```

How can I make it so when I click a category name, it goes to that specific category page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to attach a form with submit buttom or attach javascript code to make the dropdown interact with your selections.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

```
<form id="category-select" class="category-select" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
</form>
```

Or

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>    
<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
        function onCatChange() {
            if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
                location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
            }
        }
        dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
        -->
    </script>
```

Comment: Hey the second code your wrote works but it retrieves the category ID instead of the slug of the category, how can how can I make it to return /camera-photos/ instead of /=cat=254 ? Thanks.

Comment: Try to add 'value_field'=>'slug' in your $args https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

Comment: The code stops redirecting on category click when I put that on my $args

Comment: How about change codeline location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>?category="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value; ?

Comment: It doesn't produce any change apart changing from "?cat" to "?category" :(

Comment: emmm. not sure but if you can share the sample page of html reasult I can work it out. However the key object is just to make sure the location.href will be the correct link of to the category page. you may want to do somemore R&D in via wp codex. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay... Here's the page where you can see it in action: https://store.vtxfactory.org/products/

Comment: I'm kinda new to the whole php editing thing, I'm most confortable with html/css

Comment: @SteveKess I can see your pramelinks for category is setup as /product-category/xxx. Therefore you will need to change location.href to location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>/product-category/"+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value‌​; once you add   'value_field'=>'slug'  into your $args

Comment: Hey I've redone the code, I can't load it here, maybe if you could see it on my page?

Now it works, all I need now is to take of the `?cat=` part, any tip? Thanks

Comment: yes, it should work once you take out ?cat= in your location.href line

Comment: Problem is I don't have any `?cat=` in my code now, but it appears when I load a category. Please see the code I'm using https://pastebin.com/AF73iFcb

Comment: I think it's the `preg_replace` that's adding the `?cat=` to the code

Comment: It's working now, thanks. I have a question, is there a way to have 2 `value_field`? I need it to recognize the parent category so it does `/product-category/cameras-photos/lens/` instead of `/product-category/lens`.

Comment: technically it's achieveable but will need quite a bit custmizations in wp pramelinks as well as your location.href coding. Some discussions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538265/wordpress-show-parent-category-and-subcategory-name-in-subcategory-archive-url

Answer (score 0):

Write a block with jquery code that reads the selector changes, it's a suggestion, you can make the adaptations you require

Try like this:

```
    <select id="pages">
  <option value="">Select Page</option>
  <option value="google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="hitcel.com">HITCEL</option>
  <option value="facebook.com">Facebook</option>
</select>

$("#pages").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
  if(value==""){
  }else{
    window.location.href="https://"+value
  }
})
```

Sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/xfxstudios/378jx1gL/